# order by percentage of likes and return the next row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying join two tables, an image table and a likes/dislikes table. I need to calculate the percentage of likes for each image and order by that percentage. Find the current item and return the next item.

So I've broken this up into a couple of queries, first I find what percentage the current image has.

Then the second is where I'm utterly confused:

```
SELECT *, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN liked = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS liked,
   SUM(CASE WHEN liked = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS disliked
       FROM images i 
   LEFT JOIN 
       image_like il ON i.image_id = il.like_image_id
   WHERE (liked/liked + disliked) > ?
       AND image_site_id = ?
   GROUP BY i.image_id
   ORDER BY (liked/liked + disliked) DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

I'm getting an error stating disliked is not recognised in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you cannot use a column alias in the `where` at the same level as the `select`.  But, your logic is on aggregated values anyway, so it belongs in a `having` clause.

Assuming `liked` only takes on the values 0 and 1, you can write your query as:

```
SELECT i.*, SUM(liked = 1) AS liked, SUM(liked = 0) AS disliked
FROM images i LEFT JOIN 
     image_like il
     ON i.image_id = il.like_image_id
WHERE image_site_id = ?
GROUP BY i.image_id
HAVING AVG(liked = 1) > ?
ORDER BY AVG(liked = 1) DESC
LIMIT 1
```